# Windows Socket and Authentication build failed when including Poco-Library

Tags: c++, winapi, utf-8, poco-libraries

I have written a C++ program to authenticate windows user which is working seamlessly when Poco Library (Event) has not been included. I have a infinite while loop (while(true)) that needs to be halted when no request are coming from the serer application. Socket read runs independently in a separate thread.

Compiler : MingW 7.2

C++ Standard : C++14

Package Manager : Msys2

Architecture : x64

I am getting an error :

```
g++    -c -g -D__DEBUG -I/C/msys64/mingw64/include/boost -I/C/msys64/mingw64/include `pkg-config --cflags libconfig++` `pkg-config --cflags gnutls` -std=c++14  -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Authenticate.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/Authenticate.o Authenticate.cpp
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/Poco/Foundation.h:102:0,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/Poco/Event.h:23,
                 from Common.hpp:41,
                 from Authenticate.hpp:19,
                 from Authenticate.cpp:14:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/Poco/Platform_WIN32.h:179:92: note: #pragma message: Compiling POCO on Windows without #define POCO_WIN32_UTF8 is deprecated.
  #pragma message("Compiling POCO on Windows without #define POCO_WIN32_UTF8 is deprecated.")
                                                                                            ^
Authenticate.cpp: In member function 'bool Authenticate::authenticateUserCommandLine(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string&)':
Authenticate.cpp:30:26: error: 'LogonUser' was not declared in this scope
         logonReturnVal = LogonUser(userName.c_str(), domain.c_str(), NULL, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token);
                          ^~~~~~~~~
Authenticate.cpp:30:26: note: suggested alternative: 'LogonUserW'
         logonReturnVal = LogonUser(userName.c_str(), domain.c_str(), NULL, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token);
                          ^~~~~~~~~
                          LogonUserW
Authenticate.cpp:32:26: error: 'LogonUser' was not declared in this scope
         logonReturnVal = LogonUser(userName.c_str(), domain.c_str(), password.c_str(), LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token);
                          ^~~~~~~~~
Authenticate.cpp:32:26: note: suggested alternative: 'LogonUserW'
         logonReturnVal = LogonUser(userName.c_str(), domain.c_str(), password.c_str(), LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token);
                          ^~~~~~~~~
                          LogonUserW
Authenticate.cpp: In member function 'bool Authenticate::authenticateUserCommandLine(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string&)':
Authenticate.cpp:54:26: error: 'LogonUser' was not declared in this scope
         logonReturnVal = LogonUser(userName.c_str(), domain.c_str(), NULL, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token);
                          ^~~~~~~~~
Authenticate.cpp:54:26: note: suggested alternative: 'LogonUserW'
         logonReturnVal = LogonUser(userName.c_str(), domain.c_str(), NULL, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token);
                          ^~~~~~~~~
                          LogonUserW
Authenticate.cpp:56:26: error: 'LogonUser' was not declared in this scope
         logonReturnVal = LogonUser(userName.c_str(), domain.c_str(), password.c_str(), LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token);
                          ^~~~~~~~~
Authenticate.cpp:56:26: note: suggested alternative: 'LogonUserW'
         logonReturnVal = LogonUser(userName.c_str(), domain.c_str(), password.c_str(), LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token);
                          ^~~~~~~~~
                          LogonUserW
```

If I remove `#include <Poco/Event.h>` the program works properly without error.

If I add `#define POCO_WIN32_UTF8`, I have to replace `LogonUser` with `LogonUserW`. The biggest issue I have with adding `#define POCO_WIN32_UTF8` is that I am getting an error at `::GetLastError()` saying function not found.

LoginUser Usage :

```
if(password.length() == 0)
        logonReturnVal = LogonUser(userName.c_str(), domain.c_str(), NULL, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token);
    else
        logonReturnVal = LogonUser(userName.c_str(), domain.c_str(), password.c_str(), LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token);
```

::GetLastError() Usage :

```
string Error::GetLastErrorAsString(void)
{
    //Get the error message, if any.
    DWORD errorMessageID = ::GetLastError();
    if(errorMessageID == 0)
        return string(); //No error message has been recorded

    LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;
    size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                                 NULL, errorMessageID, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);

    string message(messageBuffer, size);

    //Free the buffer.
    LocalFree(messageBuffer);

    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had included `Poco/Event.h` before `windows.h`. `Poco/Event.h` needs `#define POCO_WIN32_UTF8` to be defined before including the header which caused the problem.

The problem was solved by including `windows.h` before defining `#define POCO_WIN32_UTF8` which in turn was defined before including `Poco/Event.h`.